# x86 hardware Interrupt is not working on qemu

Tags: c, x86, kernel, qemu

I'm writing a kernel (using qemu to simulate) for x86 as a school project and I ran into weird problem. 
Even though I have set the interrupt flag in the eflags register, I'm sill not getting any clock interrupts (I checked with qemu info register command and I see eflag=0x292 which means it is set).

To be precise when I run a spin test (while(1); program) in user mode, I get one clock interrupt, but after that one, it stops, qemu does not seems to simulate more! did it happen to anyone else? Is there another mechanism that can affect interrupts? 
Anyone have a clue?
Shai.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently in x86, you have to acknowledge clock interrupts after each one.
I.e one must sent an acknowledgment to the lapic after every clock interrupt.

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting interrupts from the RTC, you must acknowledge the previous interrupt first by reading from REG_C (CMOS register 0x0C).